# Unix Timestamp to PHP Year Month and Day Conversion Off

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

We are in the process of moving our domain to a new dedicated server we recently purchased. The new server's time zone is causing some issues with our attachments php code.

Our forum software uses the following folder structure to store attachments:

/public_html/forum/files/2016/February/14/[Filename]

The year, month and day are obtained from the File Upload Time Stamp which is a Unix Timestamp such as "1455426488". This timestamp is then converted to year, month and day using the following php code:

```
$date = getdate((int)$attachment['filetime']);
$filepath = $config['upload_path'] . '/' . (string)$date['year'] . '/' . $date['month'] . '/' . (string)$date['mday'];
```

This worked fine on our old server and the server before it, but on the new server the "day" is either 1 day behind or one day ahead when converted, which causes "February 14" file uploads to either end up in "February 13" folder or "February 15". Keep in mind that file Upload time of 1455426488 in unix timestamp is 02/14/2016 at 5:08am UTC Timezone.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue? This is a critical part of our forum system, so without coming up with a solution for it we won't be able to migrate to the new server.

Thanks,

Pete

BTW, both the old and the new server are using the "America/Chicago" as their timezone (CST).

Comment: You may try `$date = (int)$attachment['filetime'];
$filepath = $config['upload_path']."/".date("Y",$date)."/".date("F",$date)."/".date("d",$date);`

Comment: What timezone is PHP (America/Chicago?)  What timezone is the server/OS(date +%Z)?

Comment: @user2182349 - The PHP timezone is "America/Chicago" and the Server/OS Timezone is "CST".

Comment: @user2352577L - Your suggestion did not fix the issue. The script is still not able to find the right file.

Comment: Try adding date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); on the top of your php function where the datetime is converted to unix timestamp.. See if this works..

Comment: @DpĚN - I tried that as well, but it didn't help because sometimes the file is in the previous day folder and sometimes in the next day folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime class in order to convert your dates.

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$date->setTimeStamp((int)$attachment['filetime']);
$filepath = $config['upload_path'] . '/' . $date->format('Y') . '/' . $date->format('F') . '/' . $date->format('d');
```

Comment: Although your suggestion did reduce the error range it did not completely eliminate all the errors. For approximately half of the files your suggestion works, whereas for the other half it does not.

Comment: If All your `(int)$attachment['filetime']` are in UTC, it sshould works. So my question is, you sure all your upload time are on the same timezone?

Comment: I am pretty sure that all the filetimes are in UTC, since this exact setting was working on the previous forum.

Comment: Can you provide an problematic case: uplodad time, path you' re expecting, wrong path you get

Comment: Here is an example: File Upload time: 1455426488, UTC Date and Time: 02/14/2016 @ 5:08am (UTC). The file is expected to show up in the 14 folder, but it actually shows up in the 13 folder. So basically I get /2016/February/14 but in reality the file is in /2016/February/13. Of course I have other ones that have the reverse problem.

Comment: Ok so maybe i didn't understand at the first time but you need the folder path to be in UTC date right?

so you should do `$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));`

Comment: I tried that too and sadly that didn't work either. This is a very frustrating issue because the time shift is never in 1 direction. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It looks like the following line had found it's way into the download/file.php file:

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
```

This line did not exist in the original file, so removing it resolved the issue! I am still not sure how this line got added, but it explains the weird behavior.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: the `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');` has change the time zone of php which make you get the wrong time after you did every php datetime format.